# Solving an implicit function using Matlab

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, mathematical-modeling

In the article in  [here,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40254919?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), there is a function as (Appendix A, equation (1))
[image].
In order to find `k` in this function it is mentioned in the article that following implicit function should be solved

[image]
The values of $l_0, l_p,r_e, r_h $ are known and the only unknown is `k`. So, I tried to find the value of `k` using both Matlab by,

```
l_0=100;
r_e=log(2)/6;
r_h=log(2)/(21*24);
l_p=10^7;

syms k
eqn = l_p-(k*l_0*((r_e-r_h)*(k-l_0))^(1-(r_h/r_e))/((r_h*l_0)^(-r_h/r_e)*(r_h*l_0*(k-l_0)+l_0*(r_e-r_h)*(k-l_0)))) == 0;
k2 = solve(eqn,k);
```

But it doesn't come up with a solution for a long time.
Why is it and how can I fnd the value of `k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Matlab user but I suspect that you need a solver to which you can pass an initial estimate.

Using your equation and numbers, we end with $$f(k)=10^7-\frac{\sqrt[42]{5} \,\,83^{83/84}\, k}{42\, 2^{41/42} \,\sqrt[84]{k-100}}$$ and  the solution seems to be "around" $k=l_p$.

So, using $k_0=10^7$, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & k_n \\
 0 &  10^7 \\
 1 & 1.2260991288363371123\times 10^7 \\
 2 & 1.2263832281094110974\times 10^7 \\
 3 & 1.2263832285012184615\times 10^7
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Changing $l_p$ fro $10^7$ to $10^{15}$, the iterations would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & k_n \\
 0 &  10^{15} \\
 1 & 1.5296893921874829806\times 10^{15} \\
 2 & 1.5311290105118601855\times 10^{15} \\
 3 & 1.5311290185739798373\times 10^{15} \\
 4 & 1.5311290185739798376\times 10^{15}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Looking at the online documentation for Matlab , it seems that

```
 S = vpasolve(eqn,var,init_guess)
```

would do the job.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As I only want an approximate value for `k`, even from the initial guess alone can I choose $k=10^7$ . I don't understand why you changed $l_p$ from $10^7$ to $10^15$? Is it as an example?

Comment: @sam_rox. You need to solve the equation. Provide as an initial guess $l_p$ to **vpasolve** and let it running. What is surprising to me is that, using $k_0=10^3$, the first iterate of Newton method is $1.1096\times 10 ^7$. Changing to $10^{15}$ was just an example for showing how well the method works.

Comment: I just want to clarify. THe result I get through ` S = vpasolve(eqn,var,init_guess)` would be similar to the Newton's iterations is it? Because, from  `S = vpasolve(eqn,var,init_guess)` I get a value of 1.2263832*10^7, which is similar to what is obtained from Newton's iterations

Comment: @sam_rox. Providing **k2 = vpasolve(eqn,k,l_p);** will start (I guess) Newton iterations rather close to the solution. In fact, I am sure that we could provide even a better starting point but this one is simple and fine.